# Include the word chapter in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

**How to add the word Chapter before the introduction chapter?**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{siugrad51}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}



 \begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-0.45in} {CHAPTER} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
%\addcontentsline



%\addtocontents{toc}{{CHAPTER}{PAGE}\par}


\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}

\addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{-0.15in} \underline{TABLE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{-0.15in} \underline{FIGURE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
%\listoftables        % comment out if no tables
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}


\tableofcontents
%\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendicname~}
{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoftables%
}


{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoffigures%
}


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\raggedright
\parindent=.35in


\input{introduction}

\chapter{Introduction}


\section{Emerging Trends}





\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
% chaptertocprob.tex  SE 576370

%\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{siugrad51} %% I do not know/have this class
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter } % put this before chapter number
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em} % more space for enhanced chapter number

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-0.45in} {CHAPTER} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
%\addcontentsline

%\addtocontents{toc}{{CHAPTER}{PAGE}\par}

\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}

\addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{-0.15in} \underline{TABLE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{-0.15in} \underline{FIGURE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
%\listoftables        % comment out if no tables
%\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}  %% don't do this here

\tableofcontents

%\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendicname~}
{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoftables%
}

{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoffigures%
}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\raggedright
\parindent=.35in

%%\input{introduction}  % not made available

\chapter{Introduction}


\section{Emerging Trends}

\end{document}
```

The above MWE is basically yours but I have added in the `tocloft` commands to put **Chapter** before the chapter number in the ToC. In order to make this work I had to comment out your `\renewcommand{\numberline}...` just before your `tableofcontents`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with the `\titlecontents` command, from `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}%{siugrad51}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\medskip}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace \thecontentslabel.\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

 \begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-0.45in} {CHAPTER} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}

\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}

\addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{-0.15in} \underline{TABLE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{-0.15in} \underline{FIGURE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
%\listoftables % comment out if no tables
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}

\tableofcontents
{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoftables%
}

{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoffigures%
}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\parindent=.35in

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Emerging Trends}

\end{document}
```

[image]